# Sort a list of cdef objects by attribute in a cdef class

Tags: python, sorting, cython

I would like to sort the list `inner` of this class. The list contains objects of a cdef class called `Edge`. The Edge class contains a member variable called `savings`. I would like sort the list by this variable.

```
cdef class Alist:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inner = []
    cdef list inner
    cdef void append(self, Edge a):
        self.inner.append(a)
    cdef void pop(self, int a):
        self.inner.pop(a)
    cdef void insert(self,int pos,Edge a):
        self.inner.insert(pos,a)
    cdef int index(self,Edge a):
        if a in self.inner:
            return self.inner.index(a)
        return -1
    cdef Edge get(self, int i):
        return <Edge> self.inner[i]
    cdef void sort(self):
        self.inner.sort(key = lambda c : c.Savings)
        #self.inner.sort()
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.inner)

    def __richcmp__(Edge self, Edge other,int op):
        if op == 0:
            if self.inner.savings < other.inner.savings:
                return True
        return False
```

In order to do that, I created the method `sort` inside the class, but when I execute it, I obtain the following error message:

> Exception AttributeError: "'fib.Edge' object has no attribute 'savings'" in 'fib.Alist.sort' ignored

Answer (score 0):

### What is going wrong here

The Python- lambda function can not access the cdef attribute of `Edge`. If you try to directly access the attribute of a cdef class from python you will get an error unless you add either the `readonly` (for read access) or the `public` (for read and write access) to the attribute definition.

Take this Edge class for example:

```
cdef class Edge:
    cdef readonly int savings # visible from python
    cdef int foo # not visible from python

    def __init__(self, int s):
        self.savings = s
        self.foo = 42

    def __repr__(self):
        """Friendly representation so we can see how the edges sort."""
        return "Edge: {}".format(self.savings)
```

If we compile this (assume it resides in the file `sortlist.pyx`) and import it in a Python shell:

```
In [1]: import sortlist as sl

In [2]: e = sl.Edge(42)

In [3]: e.savings
Out[3]: 23

In [4]: e.foo
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-3ebfe6d526e9> in <module>()
----> 1 e.foo

AttributeError: 'sortlist.Edge' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

If you access the `readonly` attribute `saving` everything works, but the Cython only attribute `foo` throws the error you are getting. It is not that the attribute is not there, Python just can not see it.

### Working example

Basically the fix is: Add `readonly` to the declaration of savings in the Edge class. The Edge class above works with the following code.

```
cdef class Alist:
    cdef list inner

    def __init__(self):
        self.inner = []

    cdef void append(self, Edge a):
        self.inner.append(a)

    cdef void sort(self):
        self.inner.sort(key = lambda c : c.savings)

def test_sorting():
    # create edges with saving between 0 an 9
    edges = [Edge(i) for i in range(10)]
    # create an intersting instance for sorting
    shuffle(edges)
    al = Alist()
    # fill the inner list
    for e in edges:
        al.append(e)
    print("Finished Alist:", al.inner)
    al.sort()
    print("Sorted Alist:", al.inner)
```

### Why you might not need **richcmp** (where it is now)

When you define a `__richcmp__` method in `Alist` it can be used to compare two `Alist` objects. Hence the typing as Edge is not useful here.

What you could do is define a `richcmp` method for `Edge`, meaning a method that can be used to compare two `Edge` objects. I would strongly advise to implement **all** comparisons then. Because like it is now it might show some weird behavior like

```
In [1]: e1 = Edge(42)

In [2]: e2 = Edge(42)

In [3]: e3 = Edge(23)

In [4]: e1 < e2
Out[4]: False
# How it is supposed to be

In [5]: e1 == e2
Out[5]: False 
# This should be True

In [6]: e1 < e3
Out[6]: True
# How it is supposed to be

In [6]: e1 <= e3
Out[6]: False
# This should be True
```

because all comparisons that are not `op=0` which is the `<` operation (also available as `cpython.object.Py_LT`) default to False. So if you want to use this, go all the way.

More details on rich comparison can be found [here](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/special_methods.html#rich-comparisons).